# Benefits of chunk_split vs substr?

Tags: php

By refactoring old code which isn't from me I 've stumble about this piece of code:

```
if(BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN != 0 && strlen($row['beschreibung']) > BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN){
    $beschreibung = chunk_split($row['beschreibung'], BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN, 'x+x+x+');
    $beschreibung_array = explode('x+x+x+', $beschreibung);
    $beschreibung = $beschreibung_array[0].'...';
}
```

As far as I understand this the string $row['beschreibung'] is splitted into parts of a length which a provide by the constant "BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN" and "x+x+x+" is appended to each part. Then this new string is splitted by the appended string "x+x+x+" and as the result an array is created. Last but not least the first item of the array is assigned to the variable "$beschreibung" and "..." is appended.

I was wondering if substr resp. mb_substr because the input string use UTF-8 could be use instead and therefore the creation of a in my opinion useless array is avoided.

So my improved code would look like this:

```
if(BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN != 0 && strlen($row['beschreibung']) > BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN){
    $beschreibung = mb_substr($row['beschreibung'], 0, BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN).'&hellip;';
}
```

Have I understand this right or is there a benefit of using chunk_split in this context which I'm not aware of.

Comment: I would prefer your second version, there is no real benefit in the first one. Not to mention that the first version could fail (resp. do something else than intended), if that first part of the description was to ever contain `x+x+x+` before already. Surely _unlikely_, but probably not _impossible_.

Comment: @CBroe
That's what I also taught.

Comment: chunk_split must not be used if the string can contain multibyte utf8 characters like äöü in German.
With chunk_split, multibyte characters can be broken up, which can result in invalid byte sequences. Better to use the mb functions.

Comment: @jspit
correct and not only that. Also html tags could be truncated. These would therefore have to be removed first by using strip_tags.
But this wasn't the point of my question.
I didn't understand why the author of this code was using chunk_split.
Now I'm pretty sure he didn't really know what he was coding either. The whole code is messy as hell, so it's a good thing I'm refactoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special function for this called `mb_strimwidth()`
See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php

example:

```php
$beschreibung = mb_strimwidth($row['beschreibung'], 0, BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN, '...');
```

You won't need the `if` statement because if `BESCHREIBUNG_PRODUKT_MAX_ZEICHEN` is `0` or longer than the string it won't cut anything.

Note that the 3 dots `...` are included with the string length

```php
mb_strimwidth("Hello",0,6,'...');  // output: "Hel..."
mb_strimwidth("Hello",0,0,'...');  // output: "Hello"
mb_strimwidth("Hello",0,20,'...'); // output: "Hello"
mb_strimwidth("Hello",0,5,'…');   // output: "Hell…" (utf-8 ellipsis)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.
I wasn't aware of that function.

Because the string could contain html tags like <br> I will run it through strip_tags before.